# How long does CFmail take to send?

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am making an app that creates a custom PDF, mails it and then deletes it. I have tested all 3 components separately and they work but when I put them together the email doesn't send.

Is it possible that the attachment gets deleted before the email is sent even though the delete is after it in the script?

Here is my code.

```
<!---Get the PDF--->
<cfscript>
    PDFBuilder = createobject("component", "form_admin.email.PDFBuilder" ); 
    pdf = PDFBuilder.createPDF(form_id);
</cfscript>

<!---Create link to the pdf --->
<cfscript>
    foo =  expandPath('../email/tmp/')  & pdf & '.pdf';
</cfscript>

<!---Create email--->
<cfmail to="will@hazardousfrog.com"
        from="will@hazardoufrog.com"
        subject="Jag intrest form. "
        type="text/html" >
    <cfmailparam file="#foo#">

    Dear #getEmail.title#, #getEmail.first_name# #getEmail.surname# <br />
    Attached is a PDF boucher telling you more information about the cars you were interested in.  <br />
    Best wishes <br />
    Jaguar <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    This is not actually jaguar this is a test application by Hazardousfrog.
</cfmail>

<!---Delete the file after it has been sent ---> 
<cfif FileExists(#foo#)> 
    <cffile action="delete"
            file="#foo#">
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput >
        error
    </cfoutput>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Sorry if the code isn't great I have only been doing CF for like 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I managed to get the answer from a work friend.

When cfmail is processed the mail is saved into a spool and periodically sent out after about 3 mins. 
In my case it meant that the email PDF attachment was being deleted before the message could be sent so the mail was not sending.

The [coldFusion mail tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html) has an attribute to send it straight away or keep it spooled.

> spoolenable : Whether to spool mail or always send it Immediately.

So to get it to get my code to work I added this line to my mail attributes.

```
spoolenable="false"
```

Comment: In my experience when an attachment wasn't found prior to going to the spool the error would look like "Detail: The root cause was: ''.        Message: The resource d:\my web root folder\file to attach.pdf was not found."  If you have access to the mail logs in the CF admin you can see if there is anything useful there or in your mail server logs.

Comment: He can't accept his own answer for a couple more days I think.

Comment: @Travis : I know, but I'm not sure I would remember in a couple of days to comment on his answer :)

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Yeah can not accept my own question for 2 days or I would :P

Comment: @Travis Since i have made the change it works now But I will check for future reference. cheers

Answer (score 4):

One other option would be to use the remove attribute of the cfmailparam tag which will tell CF to remove the file after it is sent. This way your spoolenable attribute can be true and it should work as desired. The remove attribute was introduced in version 8.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would also place a `fileExists()` around the cfmail code on whether the pdf file indeed has been created.

Comment: Oh ok. The PDF created has a unique random name so if the file is there it has been created. Is it better practice to check in the create pdf method.

(also I mainly put the fileExists() in to find if it had been delete before sending.)